# React: Why Pagination method is not working?

Tags: reactjs, pagination

im using generate radomuser api, user names are rendering fine but pagination function is not working, i dont know what im missing. Please help.

I pushed my code on stackblitz, to help you guys debug it easily.

here's the link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/to-be-continue?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (
  <div>
    <Pagination
      postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
      totalPosts={myApi.length}
      paginate={paginate}
    />
    {myApi} // this should be currentPosts not myApi
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make `currentPosts` dynamic with `useState`, listen to change of `currentPage` and `myApi` using `useEffect` and then set the corresponding `currentPosts`

```
  const [currentPosts, setCurrentPosts] = useState([])

  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    // get current post
    const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage; // 1 * 10 = 10
    const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage; // 10 - 10 = 0
    setCurrentPosts(myApi.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost)); // 0 to 10
  }, [currentPage, myApi])

  // ...

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Page { currentPage }</div>
      <Pagination
        postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
        totalPosts={myApi.length}
        paginate={paginate}
      />
      {currentPosts}
    </div>
  );
```

Forked solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/to-be-continue-swucmd?file=src/App.js